# Exception in thread "main" org.pitest.help.PitHelpError, while trying to run Android Application with Activity as Pit Mutation Testing

Tags: android, pitest

I have created one Android project in Eclipse, and I got successfully Pit Mutation coverage report with line and mutation coverage, while I have removed "**Extend Activity**" and "**onCreate()**". but if I'm trying to get coverage with Android Activity and its life cycle Pit Mutation Test giving me error.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.pitest.help.PitHelpError: All tests did not pass without mutation when calculating line coverage. Mutation testing requires a green suite.See http://pitest.org for more details.
    at org.pitest.coverage.execute.DefaultCoverageGenerator.verifyBuildSuitableForMutationTesting(DefaultCoverageGenerator.java:108)
    at org.pitest.coverage.execute.DefaultCoverageGenerator.calculateCoverage(DefaultCoverageGenerator.java:93)
    at org.pitest.coverage.execute.DefaultCoverageGenerator.calculateCoverage(DefaultCoverageGenerator.java:49)
    at org.pitest.mutationtest.tooling.MutationCoverage.runReport(MutationCoverage.java:112)
    at org.pitest.mutationtest.tooling.EntryPoint.execute(EntryPoint.java:101)
    at org.pitest.mutationtest.tooling.EntryPoint.execute(EntryPoint.java:43)
    at org.pitest.mutationtest.commandline.MutationCoverageReport.runReport(MutationCoverageReport.java:72)
    at org.pitest.mutationtest.commandline.MutationCoverageReport.main(MutationCoverageReport.java:43)
    at org.pitest.pitclipse.pitrunner.PitRunner.runPIT(PitRunner.java:49)
    at org.pitest.pitclipse.pitrunner.PitRunner.main(PitRunner.java:28)
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because one of your tests failed after been mutated by PITest.
IF you scroll the logs up, you will see what test is, e.g.:

```
2:30:13 PM PIT >> WARNING : Description [testClass=com.foo.BarTest, name=foo(com.foo.BarTest)] did not pass without mutation.
```