# Can we do Pit Mutation Testing for Android Application

Tags: android, eclipse, pitest

For java PIT tools working fine, but not able to get any coverage for Android Applications. PIT gives Exception in thread "main" org.pitest.help.PitHelpError: All tests did not pass without mutation when calculating line coverage. Mutation testing requires a green suite for Android Application. Is there any solution to get coverage with PIT Mutation tools for android?

Comment: are you actually duplicating [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36026911/exception-in-thread-main-org-pitest-help-pithelperror-while-trying-to-run-and) you already posted?

Comment: I did't get the solution. con you please provide me any docs or link so that I can able to solve this issue.

Comment: Case 1: Test Class does not Extend Any class
 I have created one sample Android project in Eclipse. In this project in a same package I have created both test class and main 
 calss. while I have removed "Extend Activity" and "onCreate()", we got successfully Pit Mutation coverage report with line 
 coverage and mutation coverage. but if we'r trying to get coverage  with Android Activity and with its life cycle then,
 Pit Mutation Test giving Exceptions.

Comment: Case 2: Test Class Extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<>
If we Extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<> in Test class, and run with Pit mutation testing for Androi application, Pit not
able to genarate the expected coverage report,this report is shows no line has covered.